# PHP echo not working after if condition

Tags: php

I don't know what's wrong but with the following.

After "if" conditions echo is not working. Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

```
    $select_query = mysql_query(some query);
    $fetch_pass = mysql_fetch_array($select_query);
    $getpass = $fetch_pass['field_value'];
    echo $getpass; //Here it is working
    if($_POST['userpass'] == $getpass)
    {
        echo $getpass; // Here it is working
        $select_storename = mysql_query("Some Query");
        $fetch_storename = mysql_fetch_array($select_storename);
        $getstorename = $fetch_storename['field_value'];
echo $getpass; // Here if $getstorename has output then getpass is working else it is not working
            $select_brandname = mysql_query("Some Query"); // This query is never executing
            $fetch_brandname = mysql_fetch_array($select_brandname);  // This is never working
            $getbrandname = $fetch_brandname['field_value'];  // This is never working
echo $gettime; // Here it is not working
// None of these if conditions are working.
                if($getstorename != null) {
                    header("location:http://localhost/stores/");
                }
                if($getbrandname != null) {
                    header("location:http://localhost/brands/");
                }               
    }
```

The concept of this is `$select_query` will fetch the password and in the first "if" condition we check whether the password is correct or wrong and then there are 2 queries `$select_storename` and `$select_brandname`,only the first one is working. If I change the order to `$select_brandname` to first then only it works, the first query is working and second one is not working and the "if" conditions are not working as well.

**Update 1**

I think this is due to failed query, how can I ignore and bypass the failed query?

Comment: Obviously that's because `if` condition is not `true`

Comment: try turning the wp_debug on and see if there are any other errors.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and let us know if there are any errors?

Comment: Bypass failed query? Why would you ship an application with broken SQL?

Comment: If the query is failing, fix the problem with the query. Use `$select_query = mysql_query(some query) or die(mysql_error());` to see the reason for the failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has the following problems:

- No testing of the return value of [`mysql_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). The queries might fail.
- No testing of the return value of [`mysql_fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php). The query might be successful, and return 0 rows.
- Output before headers. [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) must be called *before* your script produce any output, unless you have output buffering turned on. (And relying on output buffering is not a robust design.)

Also note that the MySQL extension is deprecated (and probably unmaintained). You should be using [**MySQLi**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Your code should look *something* like this:

```
$select_query = mysql_query(some query);
if (!$select_query) {
  /* Query failed. Display error page. */
  exit;
}

$fetch_pass = mysql_fetch_array($select_query);
if (!count ($fetch_pass)) {
  /* Password incorrect. Display error page. */
  exit;
}
$getpass = $fetch_pass['field_value'];
mysql_free_result ($fetch_pass);

if($_POST['userpass'] !== $getpass) {
  /* Password incorrect. Display error page. */
  exit;
}

$getstorename = null;
$getbrandname = null;

$select_storename = mysql_query ("Some Query");
if ($select_storename) {
  $fetch_storename = mysql_fetch_array ($select_storename);
  if (count ($fetch_storename)) {
    $getstorename = $fetch_storename['field_value'];
  }
  mysql_free_result ($select_storename);
}
$select_brandname = mysql_query ("Some Query");
if ($select_brandname) {
  $fetch_brandname = mysql_fetch_array ($select_brandname);
  if (count ($fetch_brandname)) {
    $getbrandname = $fetch_brandname['field_value'];
  }
  mysql_free_result ($select_brandname);
}

if ($getstorename != null) {
  header("location:http://localhost/stores/");
} else if ($getbrandname != null) {
  header ("location:http://localhost/brands/");
} else {
  /* None found. Display error page or some default page. */
}
```

Some notes about the code:

- The code uses early exit which some people find uncomfortable. The alternative is to use complicated `if...else` ladders.
- The code exits after displaying error pages. If this is inside a function, return might be more appropriate.
- The code can be made significantly easier to read if you create separate error pages and [`require()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) them in the appropriate places.
- In my opinion, you should always call [`mysql_free_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-free-result.php) when you're done with a database resource, even if PHP will clean up afterwards. If nothing else, it tends to encourage you to write cleaner code.
- **And**, you should never store passwords in cleartext. Encrypt the passwords using [**`password_hash()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash) or similar, and store and compare only the encrypted passwords. See the [Password FAQ](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.bestpractice) for more information.

Comment: Shouldnt offer md5 as an encryption option, its redundant as there are that many rainbow tables around that its a mattee of time before your hash is figured out but great answer none the less so still +1 :)

Comment: @Darren: Yeah, `md5()` is pretty bad these days. I'll edit my answer later. Thanks!